# Functions with filenames and numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a function that asks the user to enter a number of characters (call this number n) and then a filename. The script should open the file, display its contents on the screen n characters at a time, and then close the file. If the file doesn't exist, the script should repeatedly ask the user to enter a different filename.  There seems to be a bug in my code:

```
myInput = input
print('please enter a positive integer: ')
myInput = n
try:                                                                           
    opened_file = open(filename)                                               
    chars = opened_file.read(n)                                          
    while chars != "":                                                   
        chars = opened_file.read(n)                                      
        print(chars)                                                     
    opened_file.close()                                                        
    except IOError:                                                           
        print('Please enter a different file name: ')
        input()
```

Btw, I dont know what the error is, all it says is syntax error.  If anyone can help, please do.

Comment: `Btw, I dont know what the error is, all it says is syntax error.` Then you know exactly what the error is. It's a syntax error, and it will tell you exactly where it is.

Comment: Actually i will answer this question... just because the wording is fun. give me 5 min..

Comment: the syntax error is do to your try, except indention

Comment: and when you get that far you will get an filename is not a defined error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U'd rather use `sys.stdin` instead of `input` to let python take care of string encoding + a lot of small mistakes:

```
import sys

print('please enter a file name: ')
myInput = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]

print('please enter a positive integer: ')
n = int(sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]) # guess u mean this

while True: # to retry on fail
    try:
        opened_file = open(myInput) # no variable filename
        chars = opened_file.read(n)
        while chars != "":
            chars = opened_file.read(n)
            print(chars)
        opened_file.close()
        exit() # success exit
    except IOError: # format error
        print('Please enter a different file name: ')
        input()
```

Comment: you would like to use `raw_input` ;)

Comment: even on 3.4? @brunsgaard

Comment: @JaredBanton, `raw_input` has been renamed to `input` in python3.

Comment: @Mux you say 'U'd rather use sys.stdin instead of input' but then use `input` at the bottom of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    try:
        mynum = int(input('please enter a positive integer: '))
        if mynum >= 0:
            # exit loop for positive integer
            break;

        # loop again for negative integer
        print('must be positive integer')            

    except ValueError as v:
        print("Must enter an integer")

myfile = input('Please enter a file name: ')

while True:
    try:
        with open(myfile, "r") as f:
            chars = f.read(mynum)                                          
            while chars != "":                                                   
                chars = f.read(mynum)                                      
                print(chars)                                                     
        break
    except IOError as e:           
        myfile = input('Please enter a different file name: ')
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer actually builds a function that asks the user for 'a number of chars'.. Hope you like it ;)

```
import os.path
def function_builder():

    def fn():
        n = None
        file_ = None
        while not n:
            n = raw_input('Enter a number of chars: ')

        while True:
            file_ = raw_input('Enter a filename: ')
            if os.path.isfile(file_):
                break

        #pure magic that converts chars to int
        magic_integer_value_of_n = sum(map(ord,n))

        with open(file_) as f: 
          while True:
            c = f.read(an_integer_value_of_n)
            if not c:
                print("\nEnd of file")
                break
            print('\nprinting {} chars'.format(magic_integer_value_of_n))
            print(c)

    return fn

function_builder()()
```